# postgresql Duplicate issues

Tags: sql, postgresql

Brand new to postgresql and currently creating a database with 4 tables.

students, faculty, courses, enroll. When I go to insert student or for any table, I keep getting a syntax error when there is a duplicate value. Example:

Student table consists of:
student_id (integer), name (text), address (text), date_of_birth (text), email (text), and level (text). Level being whether or not they are ugrad or grad student. The only constraint on level column is NOT NULL. If the constraint was UNIQUE then duplicates shouldn't work.

table query:

```
CREATE TABLE students (
student_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT,
address TEXT,
date_of_birth TEXT,
email TEXT,
level TEXT NOT NULL);
```

My query in pgadmin4 is:

```
INSERT TO students VALUES
(1, 'John Smith', '123 Address Ave', '01/01/1901', 'jsmith@email.com', 'ugrad')
(2, 'Jane Doe', '122 Address Road', '01/01/1902', 'jdoe@email.com', 'ugrad')
...
```

My issue is whenever I go to insert my values into my table all at once, I get a syntax error. I have narrowed it down to because 'ugrad' is duplicated it won't work. If I write my query individually and run it, the values get inserted fine. What am I doing wrong or how do I proceed without having to query, INSERT TO students VALUES... for each individual row.

Comment: `(1, 'John Smith', '123 Address Ave', '01/01/1901', 'jsmith@email.com', 'ugrad'), (2, 'Jane Doe', '122 Address Road', '01/01/1902', 'jdoe@email.com', 'ugrad'),`. Note commas after each set of values. See **Examples** here [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Ahhh, I missed that in the tutorial my instructor was doing for us. That was the issue. Thank you for pointing that out.